# Android Client Always Approachable From Web Server

Tags: android, web-services, sockets, servlets

In my first deployment my Android Application maintains throughout its execution (from power on until the device is turned off) a socket with the Web Server and in a Background Service await messages from the server.

Now I was wondering if you can do the same without having a Socket open all the time.

Is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes.
It's called Google Cloud Messaging (aka. GCM)

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

it's quite straight forward to implement and you won't kill your devices battery,

Comment: Can i separate different associations with this GCM. For example If i have three separate clients connected on the same Web Server i say.

Comment: GCM is used by the following apps: Gmail, Hangout, EyeEm, Facebook, Twitter, G+, Google Play, ... give a read on the docs!